# Expression blend 4 desktop application is not recognized

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I made one application for my friend and application doesn't store or anything. Just a presentation application which has some animation and sounds.
The problem is my application is not recognized in my friend's laptop, even though that laptop has new with .net version installed 
and new silverlight installed. The application works like a charm in my laptop.
Does expression blend 4 require additional frameworks or something?

**Note**:
in configuration of that application, the deployment needs .net framework 4.0 client side, so gave my friend the setup of that one*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you building it with Visual Studio or Expression Blend?

Expression Blend building is normally just meant for testing.  It builds with a Debug configuration which is only designed to run on your development machine.

When you want to distribute your application you should use Visual Studio and choose the Release configuration instead of Debug.

Visual Studio will automatically put most referenced assemblies in the bin/Release output folder.  These are assemblies which are not part of the .NET framework such as some used in Expression Blend.  You need to make sure that they are in the same folder as the application EXE when you deploy it to another machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used certain features provided by Expression Blend, then your project (that you created in Expression Blend may have references to Expression Blend specific DLLs) e.g.:

```
Microsoft.Expression.Effects.dll
Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll
```

etc

For instance using the special effect "BloomEffect" would cause your project to take a reference to the above 2 DLLs.

Using certain other Assets would add references to Expression Blend DLLs too.

Check the References of your project in Expression Blend to see if there are any Expression Blend specific DLLs.

If that is the case, then you can't just take the output from the "bin/Debug" or "bin/Release" directory that Expression Blend produced....you have to get the Expression Blend particular DLLs installed on/shipped to that machine too.

That's the time to move to using Visual Studio to manage the proper deployment of your project.

Open the Solution (.sln) there.....and add a new Setup project for your project.

Here's a view of the different extra DLLs Expression Blend can provide:

[image]

Comment: now i get it ,but i supplied all the reference files to my friend too
i mean i sent him the entire folder 'debug' and asked him to open the application so that he dont miss any reference .

Comment: The expression DLLs dont get put in the the debug folder.

Comment: so the oly way is to deploy properly using Visual studio and make sure i give him the dll's in additional to that?
One more doubt ,i previously used expression blend to make wp7 apps and that time i made xap package,why its hard for me to make an EXE with all the dlls inside it ,so it doesnt have so many reference files??

Comment: Visual Studio Setup project, works out what DLLs you are referencing, and puts them as part of the setup. If you do everything manually i.e. copying files... then you have to work out what's needed.